# Can someone tell me what this crucifix/cross is about?

Tags: global-christianity

My grandmother passed away a few weeks ago and she left me a crucifix/cross with a chain attached to it. However, I am not sure what this style represents. Where could it be from? Who is depicted?

My grandparents where Catholics and my grandfather did a lot of work in and for the third world. The reverse side is blank.

It looks like the biggest person is standing on or inside a piramid like form.
Is he preaching? are there any special groups of 10 people? 
What seems to be coming from the mouth?

[image]

Comment: are there any other details? are you wondering what denomination the necklace is for? are you wondering who the man on the cross is? do you know or your parents what church your grandmother attended?

Comment: What is on the reverse side, if anything?

Comment: Does not look like anything I've got in the mail from anybody asking for donations. I'd say this is a genuine _cool thing_ you've got there.